# runmqsc select queue where depth greater than 0

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

I have a query with Websphere MQ. I want to list all the queue where the queue depth is greater is zero.

something like :
runmqsc queue_manager_name

DISPLAY QLOCAL(*) WHERE(CURDEPTH) GT 0

not sure about the syntax. Can someone please help

Answer (score 5):

DISPLAY QLOCAL(*) WHERE(CURDEPTH GT 0)